# writing to opensolaris ramdisk over NFS

Tags: solaris, nfs, opensolaris, sun

I want to read and write to a ramdisk on OpenSolaris for performance testing purposes. The tests would be aimed at network transmission and I want to rule out disk performance.
I set up the ramdisk on the NFS server, machine A, with

```
mkfile -nv 1000m  `pwd`/ramdisk
```

on a directory that was mounted via NFS onto machine B.
Reading the ramdisk went fine, but writing to it, just overwrote the file.
I then setup a ramdisk with

```
ramdiskadm -a ramdisk1 1000m
```

which I can write to fine but I can't access over NFS. The ramdisk is put on
/dev/ramdisk
which is a link to 
/devices/pseudo
I added /devices/pseudo to /etc/dfs/sharetab and mounted it on machine B without error, but the contents of the directory on machine B are emtpy.

Comment: I see you added a ramdisk block device with `ramdiskadm`, but did you format it with a file system, then export the file system? You can't export block devices over NFS (NFS is the Network *File System*, as in not for block devices, that's what protocols like iSCSI, ATAoE, or FCoE are for).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the high-level recipe for what you want to do:

1. Create ramdisk device (ramdiskadm)
2. Format ramdisk device with a filesystem (newfs or zpool create)
3. Mount ramdisk device on a mount point (mount, or automatically for ZFS)
4. Export that mount point through NFS (man export fs, or zfs set sharenfs=on)
5. Profit!

mkfile doesn't create ramdisks, only files on some storage area. Since you want to test performance I don't see how it would help.

Comment: awesome thanks. With the steps outlined above I was able to google more precisely and I turned up this link http://learnbyblogging.com/?p=269 which gave more detail

Comment: PS  steps I took, on OpenSolaris NFS server:  
`ramdiskadm -a ramdisk1 1000m`
`newfs /dev/rramdisk/ramdisk1`
`mkdir /ramdisk` 
`mount /dev/ramdisk/ramdisk1 /ramdisk` 
`share -F nfs -o rw /ramdisk` 
`chmod 777 /ramdisk` 
On client (LINUX in this case) :
`mkdir /ramdisk` 
`mount -t nfs  -o  'rw,bg,hard,nointr,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,tcp,nfsvers=3,timeo=600'  server_machine:/ramdisk /ramdisk
`
Now, on the client I can read and write to the ramdisk and avoid the disk speed issues:
`time  dd if=/ramdisk/toto of=/dev/null bs=1024k count=800
838860800 bytes (839 MB) copied, 7.74495 seconds, 108 MB/s`

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler solution: (thanks to Adam Leventhal for this tidbit)

On Server

```
 share -F nfs -o rw /tmp
```

On client:

```
   mkdir /tmpnfs
   mount -o vers=4,rsize=32768,wsize=32768 server:/tmp  /tmpnfs
```

works like an in memory file system.